# How to design in Java and in .XML partially?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to design in code and in java.
THis is activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:id="@+id/hello">

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is Java code what i'm trying.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    TextView txt=new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("Hello World Problem");
    layout.addView(txt);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Inside relative layout, i want to add textview in java code. but the above java code doesn't work. Error: App has stopped unfortunately. How can I code that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.id.hello` cannot be found by `findViewById` until after you call `setContentView` and add `R.id.hello` to your Activity's view. Move `setContentView` above your `findViewById` line.

Answer (score 2):

You have to arrange `setContentView` before getting views using findViewById().

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hello);

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

   TextView txt=new TextView(this);
   txt.setLayoutParams(lp);
   txt.setText("Hello World Problem");
   layout.addView(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are coding totally wrong, to add textview at run time you have to do something like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("Hello World");
    txt.setId(1);
    txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello RedHat_Father replace your java code by the following code, it may be helps you:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //  Do not forget to set your layout file before you done the mapping of the elements

    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    TextView txt=new TextView(this);
    txt.setText("Hello World Problem");
    layout.addView(txt);
}
```

I hope so this will works...:)

Comment: You are Welcome...:)...RedHat_Father
Please accept the answer...if you really find that it helps you...:)